# prevent bash from running user defined binary

Tags: bash, shell, cluster-computing

In our cluster with PBS batch system (torque) installed, we want all the users to execute their jobs by `qsub` so that the CPU resources can be well managed. However, we found that users in our cluster can still run their programs directly in their bash shell.

I have noticed that some other cluster systems have restricted users from running their own binary. Their command prompt is different from full privileged command prompt.(starting from ~>)

```
qczhan2@barrine1:~>echo $0
-bash
```

In their configuration, users can run basic commands, like `ls`, `pwd`, `cp`, and 'cd' to system folders, but when users run their own binary, the system states "permission not allowed."  It is also necessary to mention that if one tries to call user-owned binary using any `mpi` command, it is also not allowed either.

For example:

```
qczhan2@barrine1:~>mpiexec -n 64 ./abc.out
permission denied
```

where `abc.out` is a user-defined binary file.

I am just wondering how to configure the system to be like that?

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: I came from serverfault due to not having proper answer from there. And I think it should be related to shell configure, a question within stackoverflow

Comment: [Your Server Fault question](http://serverfault.com/q/609148/162212) is only 10 hours old. Not immediately getting an answer doesn't seem like the best reason to post to a not-as-appropriate SE site. If it was shell configuration for your own personal user account, I could see the question on SO, but wanting to configure it for many users isn't as much in the SO realm as I see it. Regardless, I hope someone here or there has the expertise to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the default shell for all your users from `/bin/bash` to:

```
/bin/bash -r
```

so their shell becomes a *restricted shell*.  Amonst other restriction the users are not allowed to `cd`, set or unset `PATH` or issue commands containing `/`.  This locks them into only running commands you give them access to.

Comment: But we do need allow user to mkdir and cd to another folder to manage their own data, and it is even ok to let them see the system folders as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Linux: mount filesystems where users have write permission (e.g. /home, /tmp, /var/tmp, /dev/shm) with option "noexec".

Comment: I have tried to mount the filesystem where users are supposed to work with with "noexec" option. The result is that the user can neither directly run the binary, nor execute the binary through batch system.